# Why do we reference C++ projects in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Why must we **reference** projects, for C++, in Visual Studio 2013 when we intend to use a method from a referenced project? I'm confused because we use the `#include` preprocessor directive, which is copying & pasting the code we intend to use into the same header file which is still above/before the method that is actually using it.

Basically, even if I have all the **projects** in the same **solution** file, and the header files are correctly finding each other (intellisense doesn't complain/ proper linting occurs), I still get linker errors. But even if referencing projects is purely about resolving linker errors, if intellisense can *peek*/*show definition* to the code I am importing from a separate project, doesn't that mean Visual Studio also knows which project I'm linking against?

There must be a reason why, we both `#include` and reference the included projects even now in VS 2013. Could someone help explain why?

Comment: The #include only keeps the compiler happy.  You also have the link the code.  "Add Reference" is a simple way to tell the build system that you want to link the other project's static or import library.  It was discovered to be useful by accident, too many programmers that were used to .NET wanted to use "Add Reference" on C++ projects as well.  So Microsoft just made it work that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"There must be a reason why, we both `#include` and reference the included projects even now in VS 2013. Could someone help explain why?"*

Including header files allows to use the declarations (of functions, classes or structs) from there. But to get a completely executable program there's more necessary:

1. The compiler needs to know where to get the `#include`'d header files from
2. The compiled source code from a different project needs to be linked to the final artifact
3. The linker needs to know where to get the linked libraries from

If you have header only libraries, the least 2 points won't be relevant, but Visual Studio would still need the project reference for resolving the header file pathes.

---

For Visual Studio in particular there's also the [`#import`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6.aspx) directive available, that makes it easier to link against shared libraries (and keep those as standalone projects, instaead of referenced ones from the same solution).

Comment: ...and while everything could be done manually (full include path, setting the used libs in the linker options manually...), adding the project and setting a dependency simplifies this.

Comment: @deviantfan Yup! That's what the IDE actually does (not the compiler).

Answer (score 0):

No, it is computationally infeasible for a linker to magically *guess* which definitions you want to link into your project at any given time. It's a good thing that it does not attempt to do so.

Comment: I don't know which idiot downvoted this. It's a bit of a cryptic answer for a beginner, but in no ways wrong!

Answer (score -2):

The C/C++ compiling process has two steps:

- compile (.c/.cpp) source code  into a lib (requires external .h files)
- link all necessary lib files into an executable (requires both the own compiled lib files and external lib files. After all, the external .h file only contains the definition)